# ionic 4 back button fixed to root of tabs page

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working in my Ionic 4 app and I have added a back button in my toolbar and I want to show the back button only on some particular pages.

This is app.component.html:

```
<ion-back-button defaultHref="/"></ion-back-button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

.html

```
<ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button (click)="goBack()">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
```

then in .ts file

```
goBack() {
    this.navCtrl.navigateBack(['tabs/tab5']);
  }
```